# Eclipse QuickFix Feature

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following basic [code](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/#scratch) in Eclipse:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;   
import org.junit.Test;

public class GreeterTest {

    private Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

    @Test
    public void greeterSaysHello() {
        assertThat(greeter.sayHello(), containsString("Hello"));
    }  
}
```

Eclipse correctly recognizes that *The method containsString(String) is undefined for the type GreeterTest*. To resolve this, I want to import the following:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
```

However, the only *Quick Fix* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) Eclipse suggests is *Create method containsString(String)*, rather than the above import. And *Organize imports* (<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) also doesn't do the trick.

Is there a different keyboard shortcut in Eclipse that can predict, based on my dependencies, that I may want to add the above import? For comparison, I believe in IntelliJ, this is done via *[Intention Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html)* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: `ctrl` + `space`

Comment: ctrl + space is a great tip! But it seems to only work after I add the proper import.

Comment: No. It gives you a drop-down of suggested options and then once you choose one, the import for that gets *imported*

Comment: No, for real. When I remove the imports and ctl+space on the @Test, it works as you describe. But when I ctl+space on the containsString it shows no imports as options, just "No Default Proposals".

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Space` can't give you suggestions for the parameters to be passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by adding `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers` to *Java Editor Favorites*

**Action Plan**

- Open *Eclipse Preferences*
- In the left tree menu go to *Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites*
  [image]
- Use the button *New Type...* to open the dialog *New Type Favorite*
- Here use the button *Browse...* to open the dialog *Type Selection*
- Write in the text field *Choose type name*: `CoreMatchers`
  This should show the matching classes. Select the one you require, in case there are multiple.
  [image]
- Then use the button *OK* to close the window
- Back in the dialog *New Type Favorite*
  Here the selected class should be shown
  [image]
- Close the dialog with the button *OK*
- In the dialog *Preferences* the class should now be listed under *Favorites*
- Close the dialog *Preference* by using the button *Apply and Close*

Now go back to the error in your editor and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
This should show the wished match!
[image]

Comment: Nice! This is not at all what I expected, but it works. Thanks, Verhagen!

Comment: In the dialog _Prefences_ read the text under _Favorites_ as it explains where the list is for. And that's exactly what you where looking for.

Comment: Yep, I concur. Thanks!